# Test sidekiq job is created with delay_until

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I am using the delay_until functionality of sidekiq like this:

```
email.check_for_response_jid = CheckForResponse.delay_until(email.check_for_response).perform_async(email.id)
```

Is there any way I can test that the job is created when called like this?